# Automation of sum( ) in Excel

Tags: excel, scripting, automation, sum

I have an excel sheet say **First.xls** with some columns, looks like :

```
Sno   Type   Desc
 1    Hard   xxxx
 2    Soft   yyyy
 3   Medium  zzzz
 4    Hard   aaaa
 5   Medium  zbzb
 6   Medium  acac
 n    Soft   nnnn
```

I'm looking to calculate the sum based on `Type` column. Like for the above specified sheet the result be populated in a new Excel Window say **Final.xls**, which has the following data in it :

```
Hard   Medium   Soft
 2        3       2
```

Is this possible via some scripting which will be more Automated process rather than doing in Excel ?

Comment: What's wrong with the sumif function in excel?

Comment: Maybe he uses an old version? But I would also say "use countif"

Comment: Well i'm not sure about using it and calling from different excel windows .. can you show me some sample ways of using'em

Comment: Try [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/countif.php) as stated above this uses the countif method of excel and would work nicely in your case.

Comment: Thanks for countif, i'm able to do it; anyways to overcome the manual work for this problem ?

Comment: Is there more than 3 cells maybe thousands?

Comment: use a pivot table with a count for some field

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible to do this via a script like a script in python, but for that you will need to read the data from the excel sheet(refer to http://blog.nerdstogeeks.com/2011/05/reading-excel-data-using-python.html to learn how to extract data from excel sheet). Once you have the data, its simple.

final_list = { } #create a dictionary to store final values

suppose your data is in another dictionary data_list, for eg

data_list[0] = ["1", "Hard", "xxxx"]

//now to create final list

```
for elem in range(len(data_list)):
    if final_list.has_key(data_list[elem][1]):
        final_list[data_list[elem][1]] = final_list[data_list[elem][2]] + 1
    else:
        final_list[data_list[elem][1]] = 1
```

hence you will get the required data in final_list and you can write it to excel sheet back.